# Send new HTML page and make GET request to it after POST request from original page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm new to Node.js and JavaScript. I have a specific problem but mostly need advice on the best solution.

I'm running a Node server. I want the client to be able to submit a string to the server, then the server to display a new HTML page that shows the string data.

I'm using Express and Socket.io.

In the following files, the client sees `index.html`, then after submitting the form it sees `return.html`. I print the input string to the console, and the output is as expected (whatever the user enters). But the `return.html` is never updated with the input string.

I also tried sending the `return.html` page and the `change_result` call in an async series, but the `sendFile` function never ends and the second function in the series is never called. In previous attempts it worked intermittently with a `setTimeout` around the `emit('change_result')` function.

Why doesn't the call to `change_result` do anything? I used the same technique to update the headings of the original `index.html` in previous versions. Should I be routing to `localhost.../return.html` and sending the post data there, or something like that?

**server.js**

```
var express    = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io     = require('socket.io')(server); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser') //for POST request
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("Server running on port 8080.");
});

var dir = __dirname;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(dir + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var query1=req.body.input1
  console.log("Server: In post request.")
  console.log(query1);
  res.sendFile(dir + '/return.html');
  io.emit('change_result', {
    result: query1
  });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="body">
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080">
String: <input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" />
<input type="submit" id="button1" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**return.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="body">
<p id="heading1">Result: </p>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('change_result', function(data) {
      document.getElementById('heading1').innerHTML = "Result: \""+data.result"\"";
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not knee-deep inside socket.io, but IMO the problem is, that the server has no way to know if any listeners are ready.

I think you should emit a 'ready' event, once the return.html is loaded, then listen to 'change_result'. Also separate the socket communication from the POST response on the server. Like so.

server.js

```
var query;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(dir + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    query = req.body.input1;
    console.log("Server: In post request.");
    console.log(query);
    res.sendFile(dir + '/return.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('ready', function() {
        socket.emit('change_result', {result: query});
    });
});
```

return.html

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var socket = io();
        socket.emit('ready', function(data) {});
        socket.on('change_result', function(data) {
            document.getElementById('heading1').innerHTML = "Result: \""+data.result + "\"";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Would you recommend doing this another way? With different libraries?

Comment: This works, thanks. But I don't understand how. The `socket.on('change_result')` comes after `socket.emit('change_result')`, so how does it know what to do?

Comment: The order doesn't matter here. Once you start your server, it will be listening for the 'ready' event. When the return.html is loaded in the browser, it emits 'ready, therefore the server knows that the client is actually ready and loaded, and it can emit 'change_result' with the necessary data. The listener for change_result in return.html will then execute the callback and append the data to the element.